# Streaming digit-to-digit conversion from decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: substrings, string-matching, base-conversion, numeral-representations

I am looking for a [streaming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm) for converting a decimal number to a hexadecimal number.  I am assuming the input is a string represention of a decimal number (i.e., each character is a decimal digit) in digit-reversed order, and I'd like the output to be a string represention of a hexadecimal number (i.e., each character is a hex digit) in digit-reversed order.

By streaming, I mean that I'd like the algorithm to start producing hexadecimal digits without having to look at the entire decimal-string input first (i.e. up to some fixed number of digits of input can be looked at before producing digits of output); and ideally with only a constant amount of memory.

Is there a way to do this?

I know one can convert from hexadecimal to binary in a streaming way.  For single-digit numbers, we can use the following table:

```
hex -> bin
0 -> 0000
1 -> 0001
2 -> 0010
3 -> 0011
4 -> 0100
5 -> 0101
6 -> 0110
7 -> 0111
8 -> 1000
9 -> 1001
a -> 1010
b -> 1011
c -> 1100
d -> 1101
e -> 1110
f -> 1111
```

For multiple-digit numbers, we can do the same by applying the mapping above to each hexadecimal digit individually.

```
1234 -> 1, 2, 3, 4 -> 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100 -> 0001001000110100
```

Is there a way to do something like this, converting from decimal to hexadecimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Changing a high-order digit in a base-10 number -- say, changing 5000000 to 6000000 -- can change bits in its binary equivalent all the way from high-order bits to fairly-low-order bits:

- 10**0**1**10001**001**01**1**01**000000
- 10**1**1**01110**001**10**1**10**000000

It doesn't change the very lowest bits: Since $10 = 5\times 2$, the digit in position $k$ in a decimal number is a multiple of $10^{k-1} = (5\times 2)^{k-1} = 5^{k-1}2^{k-1}$, so changing it will never change the lowest $k-1$ bits of the binary representation. But it can change the $k$-th bit, and bits in positions up to $\log_2(9\times 10^{k-1}) = (\log_2 10)(k-1) + \log_2 9 \approx 3.322(k-1) + 3.170$. This is true for any $k$, so the range of affected digits grows indefinitely as $k$ increases.

If you were, say, trying to convert between base 4 and base 8, you could group each block of 3 base-4 digits into a base-64 "superdigit", which you could then convert back down to 2 base-8 digits since 8^2 = 64.

But there is no "right" superdigit base for the bases 10 and 2, since 10 contains 5 as a factor and 2 does not: every positive integer power of 10 contains 5 as a prime factor, and no positive integer power of 2 does, so by the uniqueness of prime factorisations there is no integer that is a power of both 2 and 10.

Comment: I think I understand all of your answer, excepting for this: "_But it can change [...] bits in positions up to $log_2(9×10^{−1}))$_". Why is that the case?

Comment: I mean, why would taking $10^{k-1}$ (the factor of a digit $k$) and multiplying it by $9$, all in a $log_2$, be the highest position to change in the resulting binary number?

Comment: Okay, I made a little bit of research, and now the only thing that I'm missing is where the $9$ is coming from.

Comment: The largest possible change in a single digit is from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this - if you don't know whether the input is k digits or k+1 digits, then the additional decimal digit changes all or most of the hexadecimal digits. For example 100 -> 64, but 1000 -> 3e8.

Also, consider the numbers $16^k-1$ and $16^k$. In hexadecimal, one is k f's, the other is 1 followed by k zeroes. Since $16^k$ in decimal doesn't end in zero, all their decimal digits except the last one are equal. So *all* the decimal input digits must be processed before we can output the first hexadecimal digit.

Comment: I like your first example, but your second example doesn't seem to work: we don't need to read all the decimal digits to distinguish $16^k-1$ from $16^k$; it seems it suffices to read one digit to distinguish those two.